# How to use flush() in java networking using UDP

Tags: java, networking

I'm trying to make a two way server - client communication in java using basic UDP but the problem is that if I enter a string it gets overflowed and so I think that it is good to use flush() to flush the buffer but I don't know how to use this function

**SERVER CODE IN UDP**

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class servee
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
      {
         DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
            while(true)
               {
                  DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                  serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                  String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
                  System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
                  InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                  int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                  String servo = br.readLine();
          if(new String(servo).equals("bye")==true)
            break;
                  sendData = servo.getBytes();
                  DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                  serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
          sendData=null;
               }

      }
}
```

**CLIENT CODE IN UDP**

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class clientee
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
      BufferedReader inFromUser =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
      InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
      byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
      byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
      while(true)
      {
      String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
      if(new String(sentence).equals("bye")==true)
    break;
      sendData = sentence.getBytes();
      DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9876);
      clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
      DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
      clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
      String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
      System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
      }

   }
}
```

**OUTPUT OF SERVER**
[image: This is the output of server]

**OUTPUT OF CLIENT**
[image: This is the output of client]

Comment: You can't nor is there any need to flush a DatagramSOcket, please describe your problem clearly.

Comment: @NOS If I send a message "oi" from server it gets displayed in the client as "oine" So I need to flush the garbage values in the buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is assuming that `DatagramPacket.getBytes()` only returns the sent or received data - however it returns the entire array that you used when constructing the DatagramPacket. This becomes an issue when you reuse the same `sendData` array for many receives, as old data will remain in the array when the new data you receive is shorter than the previous data received.

Your client code must account for the length of the received data:

```
String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData(),0, receivePacket.getLength());
```

Your server code must do the same:

```
String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData(),0, receivePacket.getLength());
```

Comment: Thanks @ nos it was really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* use `flush()` in conjunction with `DatagramSocket` or `DatagramPacket`. There is nothing to flush. When you call `send()` the data is sent. When you call `receive()` you will get the next packet available.

Flushing is only applicable when you are writing to an `OutputStream` or `Writer` (or subtypes) when doing *stream-based* output.

---

Hint: if the server is not seeing packets that the client has sent, or vice versa, it is possible that they are being lost in transit, or dropped by the receiver due to congestion.  UDP does not offer reliable message delivery.

Comment: But I do receive part of my last sent string and can you suggest any ideas for this?